# Skype Silent Mode

Tags: skype

So Skype has a silent mode: e.g. it won't alert you in any way about incoming calls/messages. I'd like to use that mode while working to keep Skype from distracting me. I'd rather not quit the program or signoff during that time.

Is there a simple way to put Skype in that mode? There's an option for it in their SDK but not in the software. There are third party apps that do it (among other things), but there doesn't seem to be a simple solution for this.

Help please!

Answer (score 8):

Yes. There is the mode. Just change Skype Online Status to "Do Not Disturb" (the red one).

If new message comes you'll see icon in the System Tray changed a bit. Nothing else. No sounds, no windows, no notifications.

By the way... "Do Not Disturb" mode is designed for working activities.

Answer (score 3):

Better yet...go to Tools > Options > Notifications > select what you want to hear a sound for.  And for even great keyword selectivity...at the menu go to Conversation > Notification settings and choose the "don't notify me" option.

Alternatively if you're just trying to avoid group mass activity alerts, type in keywords like "your first name" so that you will only get that sound if someone types your name. This ensures that you won't be bothered unless it's really for YOU.