# Disable unread count in the Skype taskbar icon

Tags: windows, skype

This is a Windows-equivalent question of this OSX question here on SuperUser: [Disable unread count in the Skype dock icon](https://superuser.com/questions/459686/disable-unread-count-in-the-skype-dock-icon).

Rationale: sometimes I don't want to be disturbed by incoming Skype messages (let's say I choose to process them at each break, every hour or so), but still want to be "callable" (so quitting Skype is not an option).

- I can disable visual and audio notifications...
- ... but there will still be the little orange unread count in the taskbar to distract me. Even if I turn "Do not Disturb" mode on, as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/166071/skype-silent-mode).

→ Under Windows, is it possible to disable/hide the unread count in the taskbar?

Thanks.